# ReactJs - Remplace value of a composant in a children

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a question about component in ReactJs :

I created component to do my header of my site but i have a problem;
How do i remplace value (like ,

or things like that) dynamically, maybe my question dont make sense so i give you an exemple :

If i want to do 3 pages with a similary header but the text change according to the page i am, like :

```
Page 1 : <h1>Hello</h1>
Page 2 : <h1>Hi</h1>
Page 3 : <h1>Good morning </h1>
```

It is possible ? I've tried props but it doesnt work (or i dont success to)

Concretely, I want to be able to reuse my component but by being able to modify the texts which are there

Sorry for my bad english btw

Thank you

Comment: I guess you want to take a look to react-router docs: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting

Comment: Hey Greg, thank you, i dont know if its exactly that i wanted but it seems similar so i'll take a look and see if i finlly achieve what i want, thank you for the docs !